# Sorting dataTables for date columns

Tags: sorting, datatables

I have a datatable but sorting on its date column treats the data as a text instead of a date. I'm trying to make it sort as a date instead but stuck on it.

I tried adding datetime sorting plugin but it didnt work, or  I couldnt make it work.

Here's the complete script of the page

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('.datetimeclass').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                language: "tr"
            });

            var responsiveHelper_dt_basic = undefined;
            var breakpointDefinition = {
                laptop: 1366,
                tablet: 1024,
                phone: 480
            };


            $('#dt_basic').dataTable({
                // Tabletools options:
                //   https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options
                "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-sm-4 col-xs-4 hidden-xs'T>r>" +
                        "t" +
                        "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i>>",
                "oTableTools": {
                    "aButtons": [
                    "copy",
                    //"csv",
                    "xls",
                       {
                           "sExtends": "print",
                           "sMessage": "Generated by Derimod <i>(press Esc to close)</i>"
                       }
                    ],
                    "sSwfPath": "/Scripts/plugin/datatables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "columnDefs": [
                { "type": "datetime", targets: 7 }
                    ]
                },
                "autoWidth": true,
                "preDrawCallback": function () {
                    // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
                    if (!responsiveHelper_dt_basic) {
                        responsiveHelper_dt_basic = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#dt_basic'), breakpointDefinition);
                    }
                },
                "rowCallback": function (nRow) {
                    responsiveHelper_dt_basic.createExpandIcon(nRow);
                },
                "drawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                    responsiveHelper_dt_basic.respond();
                }
                , paging: false
                // , "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, "All"]],
                //"iDisplayLength": 10,
                //,'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
            });
        });
```

How can I solve my problem?

EDIT: An example of my date format:     14.6.2017 11:49:47

Comment: Please show what kind of data you are using, how does the dates look like?

Comment: Added an example of date format